# Which type of error is generated by this code in C? Syntax or Semantic?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, syntax-error, semantics

Which error does the following code generates? According to the information which I have read so far, a syntax error is recognized mostly in compile-time, and a semantic error is recognized at run time. So does the following code throws a syntax error?

```
void f(){
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think there's any bug - think of that and you'll have your answer.

Comment: https://replit.com/@robertwharvey/DisloyalFrequentUnix#main.c -- See the red squiggly line?  Hover your mouse over that.

Comment: `semantic error is recognized at run time` - this is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is detected at compile time.

The meaning of "syntax error" generally includes *some* analysis that goes beyond the formal grammar, especially since the compiler is probably implemented using a recursive descent parser or otherwise has embedded logic that goes beyond what the pure math of a formal parser would entail.  C, in particular, requires some feedback between the lexer and the parser and can't be a pure context-free grammar parser.  (if you are interested, it's because `typedef` names must be understood as types when following the grammar)

If you're a developer, you'll call this a "syntax error" because it's easily found by the compiler, naturally as part of what it needs to understand in order to generate code.  It doesn't require a deeper static analysis than what it has to do anyway.

If you're a CS student studying parsers and grammar, you'll notice that it's *grammatically* correct, but the error is in what is being stated.  That means it is not a syntax error but an error of semantics.

That formal distinction is not very useful in real life, as real languages require some semantic knowledge in order to parse.  So the *parser* can indeed be the agent issuing the error, since it's been set up to want a bare keyword with no argument, earlier in the process.  So it is a matter of syntax to such an implementation, but the semantic analysis was applied to modify the parser, earlier.

In short, it depends on your definitions.  If the definition chosen is something about the implementation of the tool, then you can't really say in the abstract.